# How to debug Geth's go code from within Intellij Webstorm?

Tags: go-ethereum, golang, geth-debugging

I would like to be able to debug through Geth's Go code - using Intellij Webstorm.

Ideally, I would like to run a, private, Geth node inside of Webstorm and set a breakpoint, but I would also settle for remotely connecting to a local node that I have started from the command line.

It looks to me as if the entry point for Geth is [main.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/cmd/geth/main.go), however, when I try to run this I get the following errors:

```
.go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth/main.go
# command-line-arguments
cmd/geth/main.go:112: undefined: configFileFlag
cmd/geth/main.go:143: undefined: initCommand
cmd/geth/main.go:144: undefined: importCommand
cmd/geth/main.go:145: undefined: exportCommand
cmd/geth/main.go:146: undefined: removedbCommand
cmd/geth/main.go:147: undefined: dumpCommand
cmd/geth/main.go:149: undefined: monitorCommand
cmd/geth/main.go:151: undefined: accountCommand
cmd/geth/main.go:152: undefined: walletCommand
cmd/geth/main.go:154: undefined: consoleCommand
cmd/geth/main.go:154: too many errors
```

Is someone able to help me with exactly how I can start Geth from within Webstorm i.e. not from the compiled, geth, binary, please?

--- Update after trying to run from the package instead of a file ---

Unfortunately, when I set the package to "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth" I get the following errors:

```
/usr/local/go/bin/go build "-ldflags=-linkmode internal" -o /tmp/___main_go github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth

# github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth

github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/karalabe/hid(.text): relocation target __pthread_unwind_next not defined

github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/karalabe/hid(.text): undefined: "__pthread_unwind_next"
```

Comment: its look like you didnt go get the dependencies

Comment: did you solve it? I also have the same problem. I am compiling with go compiler tough, the standard one. It can't find config file and other variables are not set, exactly as you do. I am running with `go run ... geth.go`. Did you found out how to remove those errors?

Comment: Yes, I've managed to solve the problem. I noticed that I wasn't on Go 1.9 and after I updated to the latest version of Go the errors went away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure you have the latest version, EAP 15, 173.2696.28, and you are using the latest version of Go, 1.9, as that's preferred for a better debugging experience due to the recent improvements in Go with regards to debugging.

Then, go to Run | Edit Configurations | Go Applications | select the run configuration you want to edit | Run kind and change it to `File` from `Package`. Then type the name of the package, for example, `github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth` and save the settings. Then go to Run | Debug... and select the run configuration you've edited previously and select that as a debug run.

I've also created a small video which should guide you on how to change the `Run kind` for a Run Configuration, [you can see it here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ko-wKntCLjg).

Comment: Thanks for providing a video to help explain - it really helped to clarify what you meant. 

Unfortunately, it didn't seem to solve the problem - I've added more details in the update to my question.

Comment: You can omit the -linkmode in your case, that's useful mostly on Windows and Go < 1.9. In some cases it works on Linux / OSX it helps with the debugging as well but in this case it can be omitted. Remove that and try again.